# Running shell script with web2py scheduler

Tags: web2py

I need to manage some scheduled tasks controlled by web2py web interface. For that I want to utilize web2py's scheduler. First thing came into my mind is to run shell scripts using subprocess module inside scheduler function, though I am not sure if it is the correct way. Is there a best practice for that? Do you have any advices?

Comment: That's exactly how I ran it the one time I used it, if my anecdotal experience comforts you. Led to smooth results.

Comment: @salamisalem I have used subprocess module and did not have any troubles. It worked flawlessly as well. If you write your comment as answer, I'd like to sign it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly how I ran it the one time I used it, if my anecdotal experience comforts you. Led to smooth results.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on where you are hosting your web2py app.
If you host it on PythonAnywhere, you can use the scheduled tasks to run web2py's scheduler.

For example you can create a daily task as following :

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import socket
import sys
import subprocess

lock_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
try:
    lock_id = "MyApp-scheduler"   # this should be unique. using your username as a prefix is a convention
    lock_socket.bind('\0' + lock_id)
    logging.debug("Acquired lock %r" % (lock_id,))
except socket.error:
    # socket already locked, task must already be running
    logging.info("Failed to acquire lock %r" % (lock_id,))
    sys.exit()

subprocess.call(["python","web2py/web2py.py","-K","MyApp"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already stated that I am going to use web2py's scheduler. I start scheduler with system utilities, in linux via init.d script and in windows nssm so your answer is irrelevant.